# How to remember input field values when Spring form validation fails?

Tags: html, spring, validation, input, spring-form

The question says it all, whenever spring validation fails and the form page is re-rendered again by Spring, the non spring input elements i.e. those that do not have the `<form:input..>` structure lose their value. I would like to remember the values and redisplay them along with the error messages. How can I accomplish this?

Also when this view is re-rendered again upon form validation failure by spring the $(document).ready() function is NOT invoked. Why does this not get invoked. I would like to clear password fields when this happens.

Answer (score 1):

This is a great question.

In our case, we did not go with Spring validation as we implemented the validation on our classes.

But if you went with the '@Validation' annotation to validate your form/beans, you can go with the approach below

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/signup", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String addCustomer(@Valid Customer customer, BindingResult result, ModelMap map) {

        if (result.hasErrors()) {
             //add your other validations here. those which are not included in your bean validation
             //map.add(...);
            return "SignUpForm";
        } else {
            return "Done";
        }

    }
```

Then in your front-end (*.jsp,*.xhtml,*.jsf,etc), you can render those values through something like "#{myValue}".

Also, for your second problem, the only thing I'm seeing for '$(document).ready() ' not to work is if you're using jquery to do the validation and re-rendering the result to the page.

Let me know if this helps.
Cheers!